# What are the remedies as per Hindu religion to reduce parents curse?

Tags: belief, culture

Parents give curse to their children when they are very angry and actually the child also did some work which is beyond the boundary of their society culture, but the child is not wrong. The curse is not seeing wrong and right it is only the curse but I want to know the remedy to reduce the risk generated due to curses in the child life.

Comment: I guess you should recheck the tags. Some are not related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Following are some remedies by which you can get rid of “Pitra Dosh”:

• By completing “Trapandi Shraad”.

• By completing the Shraad on the date on which our ancestors were expired.

• By giving water to the Banyan tree.

• By offering water to our Pitras for the 15 days during the Shraad or on the date of their death.

• One should offer food to Brahmins on every “Amavasya”.

• By donating food items on every “Amavasya” and “Poornima” in some temple or other religious places.

For more information :- http://www.astrospeak.com/article/pitra-dosha-curse-remedies